# Unity3d, Particle system with prefab as particle

Tags: unity-game-engine

Using the built in particle system in Unity3d (version 4.1.5) is there any way of specifying a prefab (or GameObject) as the particle?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately under Unity3d 4 there is no way to use a prefab as a particle within the default particle system. That said there are several assets on the asset store that provide the feature you want.